# screen blacks out after pressing a key on keyboard, specially enter key

Tags: kubuntu

I have natty and have installed `kubuntu-desktop` package. Before installing it, everything was fine but after that, this thing happens:

When I'm typing, after stroking a key, screen blacks out, fan speeds up, and I have to turn off machine by pressing power button.

It just happens in many different apps *(chromium, hotot, kde proxy settings, ...)* and in every environment: Unity, KDE, Gnome 2.

I don't know what details must provide with this question, and I don't like to remove my KDE desktop, or re-install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug. [Report it here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Maybe it is because your system isn't powerful enough.

It would be nice if you could post the output of `uname -a` and your system specifications.

Edit: Maybe the `Enter` key is set to do something else when it's pressed. See if you can go into System Settings and change that.

Edit: To rebind the `Enter` key, make a new file called `.xmodmaprc` That file should go into your Home directly (`~`). In the file, type `pointer = default`

Edit: You might also try this: System ➜ Preferences ➜ Keyboard Shortcuts

and see if anything's bound to "Enter"

Comment: i dont think so, since it is a Corei5 powered machine (vaio laptop, vpcs136fg). this is the output: `Linux vaio598 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Did you report the bug? Has you Enter key been bound to something else? try posting the output to `cat ~/.xmodmap`

Comment: (That's your keymap)

Comment: yeah, here is that report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/801609   that file doesn't exist; i don't know why!

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I've done it wrong. So, what you want to do is reset the `Enter` key to it's default value.